# Создать словарь нужного вида

Tags: python

Никак не могу создать словарь. Файл выглядит так:

```
form pos morph lemma
gives V 3p:sing give
bird N sing:anim bird
```

Словарь должен выглядеть так. Причем 4 в этом случае частота.

```
{give{V,3p:sing}:(gives,4)}
```

Я пробовала так, но так ничего не вышло:

```
from collections import defaultdict
morphfreq = defaultdict(int)
for line in file:
    if len(line.strip().split("\t")) > 1:
        wort = line.strip().split("\t")
        morphfreq[wort[3]][wort[5]+wort[7]] +=1
```

Comment: Не получится использовать словарь в качестве ключа другого словаря. В качестве ключа в вашем случае лучше использовать исходное слово (give, bird), остальное - значения по этому ключу. Так же не получится хранить частоту внутри кортежа (tuple), т.к. вам нужно увеличивать значение частоты, а tuple - неизменяемый тип. Еще по поводу частоты, правильно ли я понимаю, что это просто сколько раз слово встретилось в файле?

Comment: http://pylessons.byethost33.com/Python5.html Вот ссылка прочитай все и выбери что тебе нужно))

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, лучше хранить "описание" слова в одном словаре, а считать частоту в другом словаре.

Получится два словаря такого вида:

```
{
    'gives': ['V', '3p:sing', 'give'],
    'bird': ['N', 'sing:anim', 'bird'],
}

{'gives': 1, 'bird': 1}
```

В первом словаре я сделал ключом текущую форму слова, а не исходную, т.к. глагол в 3 лице ед. числа - это характеристика текущей формы, а не исходной.

Реализация такая:

```
from collections import Counter

morphfreq = Counter()  # Сколько раз каждая форма попалась в файле
forms = dict()  # Словарь характеристик каждой формы

with open('file.txt') as file:
    next(file)  # пропускаем строку-заголовок
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip().split()
        if len(line) > 0:
            forms[line[0]] = line[1:]
            morphfreq[line[0]] += 1
```

`Counter` это тот же `defaultdict`, с типом по-умолчанию `int`, но с дополнительными фишками: например `dict(Counter('aaabbcccc'))` вернет словарь вида `{'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 4}`. В нашем случае можно было обойтись просто `defaultdict(int)`, но в принципе то как мы использовали `Counter` не противоречит его назначению.

**Обновление.**

Задача получения формы по описанию интересная, и тут есть свои нюансы. Допустим, нам нужно перевести слово `bird` во множественное число. Действительно ли нужно для этого нужно указывать тэг `anim`? `bird` от наличия этого тэга никак не изменится, это слово в любой форме будет существительным, обозначающим одушевленный объект. Если это не учитывать, то для получения форм можно использовать примерно такой вид словаря:

```
{
    'give': {
        'inf': 'give',
        '3p:sing': 'gives',
    },
    'bird': {
        'sing:anim': 'bird',
        'plur:anim': 'birds',
    }
}
```

Часть речи в этом словаре также не учитывается. Хотя, наверное возможны формы типа "птичий" - "birdy"? Если так, тогда нужно включать часть речи в набор тэгов.

Пусть исходный файл такой:

```
gives V 3p:sing give
bird N sing:anim bird
birds N plur:anim bird
```

Реализация чтения файла:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# Предполагаем, что файл уже открыт
d = defaultdict(dict)

for line in file:
    line = line.strip().split()
    if len(line) > 0:
        d[line[3]][line[2]] = line[0]

# Пример использования словаря:
print(d['bird']['plur:anim'])  # Вывод: birds
```

Comment: большое спасибо, но для моего задания нужно именно такую форму словаря, потому что он будет использоваться для генерирования подходящей формыпо морфологическим описаниям

Comment: @NastjaKryvoscheya, обновил ответ. Такой вариант подойдет?